# plot() returns printed list instead of sankey diagram

Tags: r, googlevis, sankey-diagram

The following code returns a printed list with `jsHeader`, `jsDisplayChart`, `jsFooter` instead of a plot:

```
library(googleVis)
options(gvis.plot.tag='chart')
s=gvisSankey(df[,c("Source", "Target", "Value")])
plot(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
options(gvis.plot.tag=NULL)
```

You can also see [this](https://magesblog.com/post/2012-10-29-googlevis-032-is-released-better/).